# Swashbuckle's OAuth fails when response returned to o2c-html

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, swashbuckle

My super simple sample Web API app is successfully rendering a swagger/ui document. But, it's failing if I try to configure it to do authorized OAuth 2.0 calls.

If you hit the icon to show the OAuth consent prompt, and then hit the `Authorize` button, I'm successfully redirected to `login.microsoftonline.com` and am able to successfully supply credentials, but, when I'm redirected back to `swagger/ui/o2c-html`, it seems that the dynamically generated javascript in that page is buggy...

**Generated 'o2c-html' page:**

```
<script>
    var qp = null;
    if(window.location.hash) {
      qp = location.hash.substring(1);
    }
    else {
      qp = location.search.substring(1);
    }
    qp = qp ? JSON.parse('{"' + qp.replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}',
      function(key, value) {
        return key===""?value:decodeURIComponent(value) }
      ):{}

    if (window.opener.swaggerUi.tokenUrl)
        window.opener.processOAuthCode(qp);
    else
        window.opener.onOAuthComplete(qp);

    window.close();
</script>
```

When I hover over the `qp` variable, I can see that I successfully retrieved the desired bearer token, but, as execution proceeds down to the final conditional statements with `window.opener` everything fails at `window.opener.swaggerui`

I get the following error:

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'swaggerUi' of
>   undefined or null reference occurred
>   Blockquote

I'm using these NuGet packages, FWIW:

```
  <package id="Swashbuckle" version="5.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

## UPDATE - FIGURED OUT WHAT I DID WRONG

In my case, I did not have the right configuration in `SwaggerConfig.cs` , in the first section for `EnableSwagger(c =>`:

I initially had it set like this (don't ask me why):

```
c.OAuth2("oauth2")
  .Description("OAuth2 Implicit Grant")
  .Flow("implicit") 
  .AuthorizationUrl(
  string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/authorize", 
   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"]))
   .Scopes(scopes =>
   {
       scopes.Add("user_impersonation", "Access swagger");
   });
```

But now it all works when I changed it to an exhaustive listing of my actual roles that I use in my controllers...

```
c.OAuth2("oauth2")
.Description("OAuth2 Implicit Grant")
.Flow("implicit")
.AuthorizationUrl(
 string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/authorize",
 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"]))
 .Scopes(scopes =>
 {
    scopes.Add("AdminAccess", "Admin access to protected resources");
    scopes.Add("FullAccess", "Full access to protected resources");
    scopes.Add("UpdateAccess", "Update access to protected resources");
    scopes.Add("ReadAcces", "Read access to protected resources");
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that is a bug in the Swagger-UI.

Latest version looks different, take a look here: [src/main/html/o2c.html](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/64dc3060b3700b12e466f8d67b7d7ec3574b015f/src/main/html/o2c.html)

We just have to publish a new NuGet package of Swashbuckle (hopefully soon)

Comment: good to know. Thanks. So, if I downgrade a version, is there one you recommend? 5.4.0 perhaps?

Comment: No, no no... 
I would not recommend downgrading, you might be dealing with more bugs there!

If this is a must have functionality for your project you should get latest [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) build it and use that dll instead of getting it from nuget.

Comment: I downloaded everything, built it successfully in Visual Studio.. then I noticed an empty swagger-ui folder and the gitmodules file.. so I ran a command `git submodule update --init` to pull down the dependent files... Now, I'm scratching my head as to how it all hangs together.. how does the .NET code absorb any of those files? I didn't see any post-build events or anything upon my cursory overview of the project. As I said, it built successfully before I even pulled down the `swagger-ui` github files

Comment: I just figured out that this was all user error on my part. See the update to my question for specifics.

Comment: Other things I did wrong: even though my web api's registration in AD had an appropriate manifest for the RBAC, I had not gone back into AAD to assign roles to any of the users. Also: due to the usage of deployment slots in Azure, my web.config contained production ClientID / Audience values, even though I was trying to interact with my 'staging' deployment slot. Once I overrode those with dedicated 'Slot' settings, my swagger client started working